# Find Inactive Computer objects in Active Directory from multiple OU's

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm struggling to make a PowerShell script and can't find a complete solution online.

Basically the script needs to have multiple functionality:

1. Needs to return inactive computer objects based on the LastLogon attribute for 30, 60, 90 days.
2. Needs to return results from multiple OU's, not just one.
3. Needs to exclude any OU with the word Laptop in it.
4. Needs to email the results in a .csv to an email address.

Please find my crappy start here which outputs 30,60,90 days but only from one OU. [PowerShell Inactive Computers](http://collabedit.com/4v4cp)

Comment: what kind of accuracy do you need for the "last logon time"? as i recall, the `LastLogon` attribute is per DC and aint replicated. the only way to get full details is to query all your DCs for the `LastLogon` info and use the newest one. here's a nifty article on the ideas ... “The LastLogonTimeStamp Attribute” – “What it was designed for and how it works” | Ask the Directory Services Team — https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works

Comment: to get all the OUs, it looks like you simply leave out the OU parameter. ///// also, you are querying 3 times for the `LastLogon`. i suspect you could query once for the  minimum time span and then filter the results for the two longer time spans.

Comment: There's a pre-built command that does this: [the `Search-AdAccount` command from Microsoft's ActiveDirectory module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/search-adaccount?view=winserver2012-ps).  You'll probably have to filter out OUs you don't want but that's not difficult.  You can use `Export-Csv` and `Send-MailMessage` to do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the required result, only thing being you need to iterate.

To get all the list of all OU's from AD you can use below command.

```
$OUs=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter *  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

To exclude any OU with the word Laptop in it, you can use below snippet.

```
$OUsWithoutLaptop=$OUs | where {$_ -notlike '*Laptop* '}
```

Then you can use the iteration as in the following sample.

```
foreach ($item in $OUsWithoutLaptop)
{
    $time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-60)
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase $item -Filter {LastLogon -lt $time -and enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogon, description| ? {$_.distinguishedname -notlike '*OU=SydLaptops,OU=SydComputers,OU=Sydney,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=domain'} |
select-object Name,DistinguishedName, description, enabled,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon)}} | export-csv $logfile60 -notypeinformation
}
```

Comment: As an aside: the `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` returns the property `DistinghuishedName` by default (along with `City`, `Country`, `LinkedGroupPolicyObjects`, `ManagedBy`, `Name`, `ObjectClass`, `ObjectGUID`, `PostalCode`, `State` and `StreetAddress`), so you should leave out the `-Properties *`.

Comment: @Theo : it makes sense. Edited the same in the code.